# In chrome console document.getElementByClassName returning extra information

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-deployment

In chrome console when using `document.getElementByClassName` it is returning an array.

But when I expanded the array, each element of array is showing addition details what are those, and why they are not coming when I print the individual element.

```
HTMLCollection(5) [div.example, div.example, p.example, span.example, button.example]
0: div.example
accessKey: ""
align: ""
assignedSlot: null
attributeStyleMap: StylePropertyMap {size: 1}
attributes: NamedNodeMap {0: class, 1: style, class: class, style: style, length: 2}
autocapitalize: ""
```

Comment: Those are the javascript properties defined by [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) interface and the interfaces it inherits from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What they are?

The properties of [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

> Why they are not coming when I print the individual element

The default `log` of element (at least in Chrome) is the Node element itself. `console.dir` will print the same as `getElementByClassName`.